# How do we update the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

This may be a dump question, but what's the process for getting the FAQ updated?  Assume it's a moderator only thing, but if we have some good suggestions come in from [meta] how do we bring those to the attention of the person who can make those edits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the idea is that if you have a suggestion for a change you write about it here, it gets voted up, and then we (the moderators) make the changes.

Note that only the top section ("What kind of questions can I ask here?") is editable - the rest of the FAQ is consistent across all Stack Exchange sites.